# docker compose ownership of named bind volume with specified path

Tags: docker, docker-compose, docker-volume

I use a docker-compose file to create service with a named bind volume, and I precise its path :

`docker-compose.yml` :

```
services:
  wordpress:
    volumes:
      - wp_plugin:/path/inside/container

volumes:
  wp_plugins:
    driver: local
    driver_opts:
      type: none
      o: "bind"
      device: /path/on/local/machine
```

This works great, except for one thing : the owner of the volume on my local machine changes from `<user>:<user>` to something like `systemd-network:65743` when I start the container with `docker compose -f docker-compose.yml up -d`

I can manually change the user and group owners back to the user by using sudo, but how can I prevent docker from doing this change of ownership ?

Comment: Files are created with the UID that creates them. That's the UID of your container process, likely from running docker rootless. There is no UID mapping for files in the bind mount from container to host.

Comment: @BMitch ok, but I noticed that if a file is already present in the volume directory on host, it doesn't change the ownership. I suppose docker doesn't try to re-create the folder, so the ownership stays the same. But if only the folder exist, without files inside, it changes the ownership, I suppose because it recreates the folder. Then I wonder why docker tries to recreate a folder that already exists.

Comment: That's the behavior of a "named bind mount" (my term). Named volumes initialize the volume from the contents of the image when the named volume is empty. Once the named volume has data, that initialization step is skipped. If you changed from the named volume to just mounting the host directory directly (`wp_plugin:/path/inside/container` to `/path/on/local/machine:/path/inside/container`), that step would be skipped.

Comment: @BMitch  ok, your proposal worked for my example but created another bug for a similar but different situation, because then it's the mounted folder inside container that don't have the right ownership :p I need to learn more about the different ways and syntax for volumes and mounted folder

Comment: If the UID in the container is different from the UID on the host, it's not unlike running a process as a different user without a container or volume or bind mount.